# Configuring biblio package / citar on Doom emacs

Tags: emacs, configuration, bibliography

I am using `Doom emacs` on a Mac with a nearly vanilla configuration. I want to use `biblio` to manage my references and from what I understand I only have to (a) comment out `biblio` in the doom/init.el configuration file, (b) configure `citar` with my paths in doom/config.el and (c) reload doom with `SPC h r r`. As I have nothing changed, my search engine should be `vertico`.

My configuration (all files and folders exist):

```lisp
  ;; biblio
  (after! citar
    (setq! citar-bibliography '("~/references/references.bib"))
    (setq! citar-library-paths '("~/references/library/files"))
    (setq! citar-notes-paths '("~/references/notes")))
```

When I try to open `citar-open-library-file` or any other related function, I get:

`Make sure to set citar-bibliography and related paths`.

`SPC h v` of `citar-bibliography` returns the expected value:

`Value ("/Users/felix/references/references.bib")`

Does anyone have an idea how to fix my configuration?

Comment: Maybe you can try to `unpin citar`?

Answer (score 0):

Someone in the meantime fixed that bug: https://discourse.doomemacs.org/t/getting-started-with-biblio/2997

It's possible to run `doom upgrade` now and `biblio` will work as expected.